# Can I create an Xbox avatar if I don't own an Xbox 360?

Tags: xbox-360

I have been following the buzz around Windows Phone 7 Series, and one of their big features is full Xbox Live integration, including the ability to see and interact with your avatar.  If I don't own an Xbox 360, should I even care about this feature?  I don't see any way to create an avatar on the [official Xbox website](http://www.xbox.com).

Comment: https://live.xbox.com/en-US/AvatarEditor?xr=shellnav it doesn't save it...
But hope you enjoy it!!!!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create an XBox Live account at http://live.xbox.com, even if you do not own an XBox/XBox 360, and you can edit many options of your XBox Live profile. However, there currently is no way to create/change your avatar without an XBox 360  w/ an internet connection.

Comment: With an update to the xbox.com website in October 2010, you now can do it on the site.

Answer (score 3):

Do any of your friends have an xbox 360?

---

If yes, you can ask one of your friends to let you create an account on their xbox, and create your avatar.  Then you can use that account on xbox.com, and see your avatar there.  You will also be able to remove that account from your friend's system, and just view it on xbox.com for now, and move that account to any xbox in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Speaking as of 2016,

**1)** You can change your avatar from your Windows Phone 8 and Windows 10 devices:

Using the [Xbox Avatars app](https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/9nblgggz5qdq), you can change your avatar from your PC or phone.

**2)** You can change your avatar on Xbox.com:

You can change your avatar [online too](https://live.xbox.com/en-US/AvatarEditor)! However, it requires Silverlight, which you can download [here](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=108181).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can create an avatar without an Xbox Live Gold (or Silver) subscription.

Comment: There is no level underneath Silver, and there is no Silver subscription. You can create a basic avatar online, just without the customization that the NXE interface on the 360 itself gives you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Windows 10 you can create an avatar using the **Xbox Avatars** application. You can access this directly from the start menu or from the Xbox application by selecting your profile then *Customise* > *Switch to avatar* (or *Create an avatar* if you haven't already)

Answer (score -1):

I think that the Windows Phone 7 series phones will have the ability to create avatars, but we don't know yet.

Answer (score -2):

go on xbox official site andthere u can create free xbox live account (even without xbox) and you can create youre avatar there for free.

Comment: Way to restate a three year old answer...

Comment: There's nothing here that hasn't already been said.